# How do I move widgets on the Dashboard that are out of the viewing area?

Tags: dashboard-widget, dashboard

I have a couple of widgets in Dashboard that moved outside of the viewing area. I can only see them in Mission Control.

[image: Dashboard widgets outside of the viewing area]

How do I move them back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to remove them (Manage widgets...) and than add again to dashboard.